# How to get my argparse subparsers format be like in a list and not on one single line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have this code as the test

```py
import argparse


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("test", description="subparser help test")
    commands = parser.add_subparsers(dest="command", title="Commands")

    subparser_a = commands.add_parser("parser_a", description="description_of_parser_a")
    subparser_a.add_argument("--foo")
    subparser_a.add_argument("--bar")

    subparser_b = commands.add_parser("parser_b", description="description_of_parser_b")
    subparser_b.add_argument("--foo-b")
    subparser_b.add_argument("--bar-b")

    args = parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but when i run `python test.py --help`, it shows something like this

```
usage: test [-h] {parser_a,parser_b} ...

subparser help test

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit

Commands:
  {parser_a,parser_b}
```

but what i expect it to print is something like this

```
usage: test [-h] {parser_a,parser_b} ...

subparser help test

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit

Commands:
  parser_a             description_of_parser_a
  parser_b             description_of_parser_b
```

is their any workaround or way to do that?

Comment: I think you would need to write your own `HelpFormatter` subclass. The documentation on how to do this is lacking, but you can take a look at [its source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/argparse.py#L154) and that of its subclasses.

Comment: that is going to take time, i have seen the above expected output at many other programs such as pip.

Comment: `pip` doesn't actually use `argparse`; it still uses `optparse`, and does write its own `HelpFormatter` class. (Though as the answer below points out, I overlooked the simply solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your code like below. `description=` -> `help=` in `add_parser`

```py
import argparse


def main():
    ...

    subparser_a = commands.add_parser("parser_a", help="description_of_parser_a")
    
    ...

    subparser_b = commands.add_parser("parser_b", help="description_of_parser_b")
    ...
    
    args = parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```